# Shin on Tefilin - changed in Belz?

Tags: tefilin, chasidut-hasidism, mesorah-tradition, safrus

I recently heard that in Belz they changed the Shin on the Tefilin Shel Rosh due to an old pair that was found that the Rebbi believed to be the true Mesorah. Is this true? How does the new Shin compare to the regular Shin that either Ashkenazim, Sefardim or Chabad uses? A photo showing the difference would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm a close Talmid of Rav Shammai Gross Shlit"a (considered the leading posek in the Belzer Kehillah and as well from the biggest Poskim in Eretz Yisrael.) I will bli neder ask him tomorrow about this.

Comment: Using archaeology to change halacha? How radical!

Comment: @Yehoshua ever got around to asking him?

Comment: @Yehoshua, have you had a chance to ask him?

Comment: @Yehoshua, did you ever get the chance to ask him?